# Looking for a way to automatically identify and maybe squash or otherwise recombine git commits in the git history that cancel each other out

Tags: git

I have a longer feature branch in one of my repos that contains a bunch of changes that are WIP and/or experimental and got abandoned after a while. Their introduction is part of the git history, as is their removal.

Now I would like to know if there's a tool or something that automatically identifies changes and can remove the hunks from the git history.

I have asked ChatGPT, but the answer is unsatisfying. There used to be a tool named `git-optimize` that allegedly did exactly this, but it seems to have vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a `git-optimize` script.

One possible approach is to list commits that are reverting other commits, with the command `git log --grep='^This reverts commit '`.

That would list both the commit SHA1 and the reverted commit SHA1.

Using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)), you can then do an interactive rebase, dropping both references [through `git replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70118599/6309), with [parent rewriting](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_parent_rewriting) (since a `git rebase -i` is *interactive*, not compatible with a script).

You would need a script to list those commit pairs and delete them.
But that would only covert the `git revert` commits. Any manual deletion which delete part of a commit would not be detected.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, exactly, the actual problem are changes that are not reverted by `git revert`.

Comment: @HendrikWiese Which is why I would not use `git revert` in this case.